# For any direct graph $G(V,E)$, there is always an iteration of DFS algorithm on $G$ so the result does not have any cross trees

Tags: algorithms, graphs, depth-first-search

I suspect that it is not true but I came across with the following statement:

> For any direct graph $G(V,E)$, there is always an iteration of DFS algorithm on $G$ so the result does not have any cross edges.

Is it possible to show an example to disprove it?

Comment: What's a cross tree? Also what's an **iteration** of the DFS algorithm?

Comment: @Steven Sorry I meant "cross edge". By "iteration of DFS" I mean, starting from different vertex.

Comment: Is there any particular order in which the edges of the currently visited vertex need to be examined during the DFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following graph:

[image]

A possible DFS starting from $a$ visits the vertices in this order: $\langle a, b, c, d \rangle$ producing the cross-edge $(c,b)$.

A possible DFS starting from $b$ visits the vertices in this order: $\langle b, a, c, d \rangle$ producing the cross-edge $(d,c)$.

A possible DFS starting from $c$ visits the vertices in this order: $\langle c, a, b, d \rangle$ producing the cross-edge $(d,b)$.

A possible DFS starting from $d$ visits the vertices in this order: $\langle d, a, b, c \rangle$ producing the cross-edge $(c,b)$.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve without anti-parallels edges?

Comment: Sure. Just split $(b,a)$, $(c,a)$, and $(d,a)$ by adding a middle vertex. Argue similarly to what I did in the answer to handle depth first searches starting from the newly added vertices.